# Getting correct labels on axes with PSTricks

Tags: pstricks, plot

Consider the following example.

**Code**

```
% latex test.tex
% dvips test.dvi
% ps2pdf test.ps

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-coil,pstricks-add}

\def\turister#1#2{%
 \psset{linewidth=0.075,linecolor=red}
  \psline(!#1 1990 sub 0)(!#1 1990 sub #2 190 sub)
  \psline(!#1 1990 sub 0.25 sub #2 190 sub)(!#1 1990 sub 0.25 add #2 190 sub)
}

\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=1.4,yunit=0.07}
\begin{pspicture}(8,150)
  \psaxes[labels=none,yAxis=false](1,0)
  \psaxes[Ox=1991,yAxis=false]{->}(1,0)(6.5,0)[{\AA}rstal,0][,90]
  \psaxes[xAxis=false,Oy=200,Dy=10](0,2)
  \pszigzag[coilarm=0.125,coilwidth=0.3,coilheight=0.5](0,2)(0,8)
  \psaxes[xAxis=false,Oy=200,Dy=10,ylabelFactor={\cdot 10^3}]{->}%
    (0,10)(0,7.5)(0,135)[,0][Antal norske turister,90]
  \psline[linecolor=blue](0,98)(6.5,98)
  \turister{1991}{264}
  \turister{1992}{285}
  \turister{1993}{290}
  \turister{1994}{298}
  \turister{1995}{275}
  \turister{1996}{316}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image: output]

**Question**

What is the easiest way to get the same labels on the x-asix as now?

I guess writing

```
\psaxes[labels=none,yAxis=false](1,0)
\psaxes[Ox=1991,yAxis=false]{->}(1,0)(6.5,0)[{\AA}rstal,0][,90]
```

is overkill, but my attempts to get it with a single `\psaxes` have failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  [...]
  \psaxes[Oy=190,Dy=10,ylabelFactor={\cdot 10^3},Ox=1990,showorigin=false]{->}%
    (0,0)(6.5,130)[,0][Antal norske turister,90]
  \psline[linecolor=white](0,10)
  \pszigzag[coilarm=0.25,coilwidth=0.3,coilheight=0.5](0,0)(0,10)
  [...]
```

Comment: You got mail ;-)

Comment: This is almost perfect: There is a very thin, non-white frame around the line from `(0,0)` to `(0,10)`. How do I remove this frame?

Comment: Arrrh! It is a PDF viewer problem; when using Adobe Reader everything is fine.

Comment: @Svend Tveskæg Which PDF viewer causes troubles and on what platform?

Comment: @PredragPunosevac Evince on Fedora.

Comment: @Svend Tveskæg Have you tried mupdf. Much better PDF rendering libraries than Poppler. Tiny, tiny libraries and viewer in comparison with anything let alone with Acroread.

Comment: @PredragPunosevac No I haven't, but I'll give it a go.

Comment: @PredragPunosevac: it is often a problem of the current magnification not the viewer